# EXCEL Averaging with multiple Criteria

Tags: excel

I have tried 2 approaches to my problem and can't quite figure out where I'm going wrong.
`=AVERAGEIFS(CALC!L:L,CALC!C:C,Consignee!A2,CALC!K:K,CALC!A:A)` and `=IF(AND(Consignee!A2=CALC!C:C,CALC!K:K=CALC!A:A),AVERAGE(CALC!L:L),0)`

Basically I need to start with CONSIGNEE!A2, then find it's match in CALC!C:C, which I then need to check against CALC!A:A to find the ones that go with it in the same row and see if that/those cell(s) match any in CALC!K:K and then take the average of the corresponding values in CALC!L:L and average them.  I hope that makes sense. I feel like I've gotten close but am missing something.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Try AVERAGEIF() or AVERAGEIFS().

Comment: If you'll notice I already tried Averageifs and I have previously tried an averageif statement as well. I couldn't get either one to work

Comment: Yes, indeed you did. I became confused by your description.

Comment: Sorry I know it's confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that the formula below may not be the most efficient possible but it will do the job.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((CALC!A:A=CALC!K:K)*(CALC!C:C=CONSIGNEE!A2),CALC!L:L)/SUMPRODUCT((CALC!A:A=CALC!K:K)*(CALC!C:C=CONSIGNEE!A2))
```

### Edit

In my original answer a reference to L1 was erroneously left over from the formula I tested where I had L1 taking the place of CONSIGNEE!A2. I have corrected this error and believe that the formula works fine for your requirement now.

Note that there are two separate SUMPRODUCT functions which you can test each by itself, one returning the count, the other the sum. If the count = 0 a #DIV/0 error will occur. You can prevent that by embedding the formula in and IFERROR() function.

Comment: This is returning #DIV/0 on cells where I know it shouldn't be 0.  I'll try to simplify the need:  The values I need to average are in column CALC!L:L, these tie to values in column CALC!K:K.  The values in CALC!K:K are unique values pulled from CALC!A:A because there are duplicates and I needed the individual numbers to count them.  CALC!A:A lines up with CALC!C:C which holds the names I need to match against CALC!L:L.  These names are in a list without duplicates in Consignee!A:A (hence the reference against Consignee!A2).  So I need the average from CALC!L:L to referenc against Consignee!A2

Comment: I hope that's easier to understand than my original explanation. It's not the most elegant way to get everything I need but my boss wanted a crazy amount of information for a meeting Monday afternoon and this was the only part of the sheet I couldn't figure out because I couldn't get it to use entire columns as criteria for some reason.  I'm not the best at excel, but our main excel guy is out right now so it got dumped on me.